# Symfony: Debug Ajax Requests

Tags: ajax, debugging, symfony

community,

i have a symfony project (3.1.10) and use ajax requests (jquery.ajax) to load data. If the request fails, the debugger toolbar shows the error but creates no profiler entry, there is only a **n/a** in the profile column. So i have no chance to get the reason for the failing. I remember in symfony 2.7 there was a profiler entry for failed ajax requests. Can someone help me?

[image: debug toolbar]

Comment: I am pretty sure it's because you get a 500 and no 4xx error, this probably means that your php code exited with a fatal error, so no php script execution anymore, therefore no profile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i remember that there was an profile entry for 500 errors. And this blog post there is it also: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-web-debug-toolbar-and-profiler-enhancements

Comment: yes, but still - there are fatals errors with PHP which are so 'basic fatal' that no further PHP execution is possible (e.g. incorrect `use` statements and so on) - and you want get any further details in the profiler about them. visit your logs if there's any additional information, sometimes it is.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the URL of your AJAX request actually uses the app_dev.php front controller. Otherwise no debug data is recorded for the profiler to display.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the same. But you know you always can open `/_profiler/` page on your instance, find your ajax call and find out what happened.

Comment: The request also does not appear at the profiler page. Just like it was never executed.